# How do I trap a double-click event on a ListView that has no items?

Tags: c#, listview, events, double-click

In my C# app, I have a ListView on a Form. I want the user to be able to double-click on a section of the ListView when no items are selected in order to pop up a "New Item" dialog. The problem is that the DoubleClick event for the ListView only fires if an item is selected.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, but you have to do some low-level drilling into the Windows machinery.  It's generally not a good idea to spend a great deal of time trying to get a standard Windows control to behave in a non-standard manner.

A simpler way is to just put a "New Item" button next to your ListView.  If screen real estate is an issue, you could just add an extra row at the bottom that says "{click here to add new item}", and show your dialog when the user clicks this last row.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for the List view's MouseDoubleClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows Forms:

Perhaps a good workaround would be to use a [`ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx).